# Keeping variables local to a component

Tags: visualforce

I was surprised recently when a Visualforce component was able to overwrite the value of a variable used in another component.  Here's a stripped down version of what I saw:

**Sample.page**

```
<apex:page>
    <c:foo title="title for foo"/>
    <c:bar/>
</apex:page>
```

**foo.component**

```
<apex:attribute name="title" type="String"/>
<apex:outputPanel id="fooPanel">
    {!title}
    <apex:form>
        <apex:actionFunction name="fooAction" action="{!foo}" rerender="fooPanel"/>
    </apex:form>
    <button onclick="fooAction();"\>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

**bar.component**

```
<apex:variable var="title" value="some new value">
```

So after the page rendered, I clicked the button, which called `fooAction()` and was surprised when the title changed!

Is this expected behavior?  Should I be doing something to keep the `title` of **foo.component** separate from the `title` of **bar.component**?  What about best practices for variable naming in components -- prefix all local variable names with something related to the component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Components are supposed to be re-usable pieces of Visualforce so when the page is rendered they're built straight into it. They could have used a namespace setup to avoid collisions such as this but I suspect just as many people would want the ability to create reusable pieces of code which depend on existing variables.

With regards to avoiding the issue I'd say using a naming convention as you suggest would be the best way forward, use a simple, unique prefix for all variables in each component.